# KQL draw a simple average value graph

Tags: kql

I have a really simple dataset - just 2 columns with datetime and a value.

```
2022-04-18T03:20:39.956Z    3
2022-04-18T03:55:22.471Z    -1
2022-04-18T04:02:40.761Z    -4
2022-04-18T04:10:41.68Z     -5
2022-04-18T04:21:19.707Z    -1
2022-04-18T04:31:53.644Z    -3
2022-04-18T04:33:40.543Z    1
2022-04-18T04:33:58.73Z     2
2022-04-18T04:41:18.17Z     -11
2022-04-18T04:47:33.845Z    1
2022-04-18T05:04:22.776Z    0
```

I need to draw an average value graph. But how can I make a bin with average values for each step to draw an average value graph

[image]

Comment: (1) Please avoid image and supply data sample in text format.(2) it is not clear what the desired outcome is

Comment: edited my initial post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what it is you are struggling with here, but here is the code.
I also added min & max values for comparison.

```
datatable (dt:datetime, val:int)
[
     '2022-04-18T03:20:39.956Z' ,3
    ,'2022-04-18T03:55:22.471Z' ,-1
    ,'2022-04-18T04:02:40.761Z' ,-4
    ,'2022-04-18T04:10:41.68Z'  ,-5
    ,'2022-04-18T04:21:19.707Z' ,-1
    ,'2022-04-18T04:31:53.644Z' ,-3
    ,'2022-04-18T04:33:40.543Z' ,1
    ,'2022-04-18T04:33:58.73Z'  ,2
    ,'2022-04-18T04:41:18.17Z'  ,-11
    ,'2022-04-18T04:47:33.845Z' ,1
    ,'2022-04-18T05:04:22.776Z' ,0
]
| make-series avg(val), min(val), max(val) on dt step 1h
| render timechart
```

[image: Avg]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3XRwW7DIAwG4PMi5R18ayslCIMJxM%20x06Yd2ILWqE02JajqoQ8/SLXLysTFhw/zGw8%20pvN%20DrAfIg8%20hjhOoYGLP/M4x0NdvdbVE%20yUVKqV1KJ7lpqVZN2L3nQvO2h0As0fYAwrJchiBi0%20CGKpmKSw3V1QQaBkQtG5BJIwBaGQsRdW2n9f0chGi45oE49Jk9A5hyGdRbFFmsYJq7cYqgAopXAC7T0nlnqQTW2EI1N%20xHAeRglrtw%20VdfVWVzeY/Cm0a1jGsIK/fO7TTg4NTOP8W/nrVsHXDEOENYZvwGO%20uYR5CAvkVX4c/RJ/AAKwL%20nmAQAA)